# select particular rows in a dataframe based on combination of columns in another data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which df1 has 3 columns and df2 has 3 columns, I want to match the rows in df1 with the rows as a reference from df2. The df1 is as follows:

```
   df1<-data.frame("id"=c("12e","13e","14e"),"name"=c("sam","susan","alex"),"familyname"=c("son","hen","ken"),"Age"=1:3)
df2<-data.frame("name"=c("sam","susan"),"familyname"=c("son","hen"),"status"=c("married","married"))
```

I want to only select the rows in df1 that has same name and family name in df2 and also append the status of marriage to the df1. 
I have tried the following code but I did not get the desire out put.

```
df3<- df1 %>% filter(df1$name %in% df2$name & df1$familyname %in% df2$familyname)
```

I want to have the out put like this:

```
name  familyname  Age  status
sam        son   1     married
susan      hen   2     married
alex       ken   3     divorce
```

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: Thanks for you reply I just revised the question. could you please check it and reply. for those rows which is not same as df2 I want the status change to something else.

Comment: In that case, you can do `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)` and replace `NA` to "`divorce"`. ?

Comment: thank you so much for your help